# How to keep track of which buttons have been pressed after page reloaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, url-parameters

I'm new to Javascript, and JQuery. After searching the internet for solutions, I decided to post this question.

**The problem:** When the user clicks on a link within the iframe, it updates the progressbar on the parent, which is only triggered once. BUT, when the user goes to another page, and comes back, the page in the iframe is reloaded, and so is the javascript, meaning that the progressbar can be updated again for that button, which I don't want. Is there any way of keeping track of which elements are clicked, after reload and disabling that function? URL-Parameters??

HTML in iframe:

```
<div id="sidenav">
   <ul>
      <li><a href="../right/section1/page1.html" target="presentation" class="active" name="position">positioning</a></li> 
      <li><a href="../right/section1/page2.html" target="presentation">comparisons</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript in iframe page:

```
$('#sidenav ul li a').one('click', window.parent.updateBar);
```

Comment: Set a cookie which contains the button statuses. It's the only way to persist data between multiple pages (until html5 local storage comes widespread enough you can assume it's always present).

Comment: @Marc B, Thanks for the suggestion. This project is currently dealing with only webkit browsers and so after looking at HTML5 localStorage, I think that suggestion might be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like `localStorage`. The only drawback is that it is persistent even after rebooting etc, but you can reset the value if your complete website is reloaded. Also it's not supported by IE7 and lower.

```
function updateBar() {
    if(localStorage['pressed'] == 'true') return; // abort if already pressed

    // do things

    localStorage['pressed'] = 'true'; // save the data that it is pressed
}
```

Comment: Now is localStorage a HTML5 capability? For this project that I'm working on is really dealing only with webkit browsers, and uses a lot of the new CSS3, HTML5 features.

Comment: @leetou: Yes it is, a great one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this works out well especially when the project deals exclusively with webkit browsers. Just one question, in that you have 'pressed', since there are several buttons, would each button have it's own trigger?

Comment: @leetou: There is only one `localStorage['pressed']`, so if you want to store it uniquely for each button you'd have to change `pressed` into something unique (e.g. button's ID).

Answer (score 2):

Whatever you want to record on the client you basically have the same choices:

- cookies
- client-side storage
- url hash

or:

- round-trip to the server and store the data in the results page

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do something like that on the server side. Keeping track of the state of data on a page is typically done on the server side, so that logic can be kept out of the interface. Makes maintenance much easier in the future.