# keep Radio Button checked after linking to other site

Tags: php, forms, input, checked

Basically im building a dropdown menu which works with radio buttons.
if a button is checked, the submenu will open. further if i click a link of the submenu, it redirects to the desired page and all radio buttons are unchecked again. How can i keep the button checked?

here's the code:

```
 echo '
 <li><label for="menu_'.$c.'"><span>'.$custom_term->name.'</span></label>
 <input type="radio" name="category" id="menu_'.$c.'" />
 ';
```

[heres the full code](http://pastebin.com/EVxtVdZ8)
might be pretty easy, but im not familiar with this aspects of php…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read a tutorial about [passing information](http://creativeprogs.blogspot.nl/2009/12/php-send-information-through-url.html?m=1) with PHP.

The steps are:

1. When the user is redirected to the other page, add the buttons which are check as a parameter to the URL.
2. Then read the URL parameters by using jQuery like [so](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.nl/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html?m=1).
3. And lastly, check the buttons on page load with jQuery's `.attr(•)` function as can be see [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/check-uncheck-checkbox-jquery/).

I hope that answers your question.

### Update

Regarding the passing of variables through a Wordpress permalink is absolutely possible. It is basically the same principle.

You can read about doing so by searching for it on Google [LIKE THIS](https://www.google.nl/search?q=adding+variable+to+permalink).

Also, please read this question: [How to pass extra variables in URL with Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586835/how-to-pass-extra-variables-in-url-with-wordpress).

Comment: tell me if im wrong but i think thats not going to work if, my links in the submenu redirect with permalinks of wordpress? also, isnt there a way to do it without js?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. You can use js or other [structures](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7111643/how-to-keep-track-of-which-buttons-have-been-pressed-after-page-reloaded). The usage of a WordPress permalink should not pose a problem (see update).

Comment: alright, im sure, that counts as an answer but, it seems too complicated to me, i might have to find another solution.

Comment: If you support modern browsers (only), you can use `localStorage` to make it easier. Like [here](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2013/03/store-data-locally-with-html5-web.html) and [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/using-html5-local-storage-in-your-web-apps). But apart from that method, there's no easier solution. If you now think I've answered your question sufficiently, please consider accepting it.